# Ordering by a custom attribute in Laravel 5 model?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a model called `customers` which has a custom attribute called `name`; this can either by a customers full name or the company name depending on what their account type is.

```
class Customer extends Model
{

    const BUSINESS = "Business";
    const INDIVIDUAL = "Individual";

    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $appends = ['name'];
    private $name;

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::created(function () {
        });

        static::updating(function () {
        });
    }


    /**
     * Get the display name for the customer
     * 
     * if Customer::BUSINESS then use company field
     * else if Customer::INDIVIDUAL then use their name
     * 
     * @return mixed|string
     */
    function getDisplayName() {
        return ($this->account == Customer::BUSINESS) ? $this->company : $this->getContactName();
    }

    public function getContactName()
    {
        return ucfirst($this->first_name) . " " . ucfirst($this->last_name);
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->getDisplayName();
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $name
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to **ORDER BY** this custom attribute if possible.

At the moment Laravel throws an error saying `name` is not a defined column.

Is there a way to do this with Laravel Query builder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will not be able to use this attribute in a query without converting this function into a SQL statement.

You can however query this model and sort it afterward using the [`sortBy`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-sortby) function. This will order your collection in memory after it has been fetched from the database.

```
$customers = Customers::get()->sortBy('name');
```

Keep in mind that this is not recommended for large collections (> ~10k). Then you should look into converting this to an SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks, I am guessing the performance of this will greatly deteriorate when the collection size gets big.

Comment: Indeed, I also added this to my answer. If your collection is really big you should look into turning this into an SQL Statement.

Comment: I think I will try the SQL statement in hindsight with a column alias

Answer (score 0):

To improve on @tomaytotomato answer you can reduce memory usage and execution time by using the Laravel cursor() method

```
$customers = Customers::cursor()->sortBy('name');
```