# Laravel eloquent order by custom attribute

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a `total_views` attribute added to my `Product` model like this

```
public function getTotalViewsAttribute(){

  return (int)$this->views()->sum('count');

}
```

`views()` is a relationship on `Product` like this

```
public function views()
{
        return $this->morphMany(View::class, 'viewable');
}
```

What I would like to do is order my `Product` by the `total_views`. Or in other words to order by the sum of the `views()` relationship.

I have tries to `->orderBy('total_views')` on the query but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45586280/ordering-by-a-custom-attribute-in-laravel-5-model : Try this

Comment: So you need to orderby relationship count right ??

Comment: @ManojKiranAppathurai yes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel OrderBy relationship count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208502/laravel-orderby-relationship-count)

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent getter can only work, when the query has been executed, therefor your current code is not working. I would always use `withCount()`, on the query;

```
$products = Product ::withCount(['views'])->get();
```

The count would be on a property named `views_count;`.

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $product->views_count; // get view count
}
```

And also possible to order by the column, as it will be present in the SQL returned by the query.

```
Product ::withCount(['views'])->orderBy('views_count', 'desc')->get();
```